# I can't display all my CollectionView items .NET MAUI application

Tags: xaml, maui

I have a problem in my .NET MAUI application. I'm trying to display a list of quizzes retrieved from my API. The problem is that only the first two quizzes are displayed. I have 6 items, so normally the 6 items should be displayed with 2 items per row. I tried deleting one of the 2 quizzes and the third one got displayed in place of the one which I deleted.

This is my QuizHome Page design:

```xml
<ScrollView>
  <VerticalStackLayout>
    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto" ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*" ColumnSpacing="10">
      <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <SearchBar Placeholder="Search" PlaceholderColor="#49B1F9" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" CancelButtonColor="#49B1F9"/>
      </Grid>
      <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="Choose Topic" Style="{StaticResource BaseMediumDarkLabelTextStyle}" FontSize="20" Margin="5,15" />
      <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding QuizesVM}"  Grid.Row="2"  Margin="30,0,0,20">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
          <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:QuizVM">
            <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto" Margin="8,0,8,0" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="150">
              <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:QuizViewModel}},Path=GotoQuizDetailsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
              </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
              <Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 15 15 15 15 " StrokeThickness="2" HeightRequest="160" WidthRequest="150">
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding QuizTitle}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource BaseMediumDarkLabelTextStyle}"></Label>
              </Border>
            </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
  </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Did you use the ObservableCollection in your viewmodel?

Comment: Please show your ViewModel.

Comment: CollectionView comes with scrolling built-in, so you don't need the ScrollView on the outside. It's actually discouraged to nest scrollable views in the [ScrollView documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/scrollview).

Answer (score 0):

You must call "OnPropertyChanged(name)" after receiving data list from API.
like that short code sample.

```cs
QuizesVM = new ObservableCollection<ModelClass>(){
   new ModelClass() {data},
   new ModelClass() {data},
   //...
} 
//Then call this "OnPropertyChaged(your binding Property name) to appear items in CollectionView on screen.
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(QuizesVM));
```